# Question about distribution of product of two independent random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

On the wikipedia page for the product distribution, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution, it says that the pdf for $Z = XY$ is $f_{Z}(z)=\int _{{-\infty }}^{{\infty }}f_{X}\left(x\right)f_{Y}\left(z/x\right){\frac  {1}{|x|}}\,dx.$ I'm curious about where the ${\frac  {1}{|x|}}$ comes from because intuitively, for every Z, the probability Z = XY is equal to the probably X = x multiplied by the probability Y = z/x, implying that the pdf should just be $f_{Z}(z)= \int _{{-\infty }}^{{\infty }}f(x,z/x) = \int _{{-\infty }}^{{\infty }}f_{X}\left(x\right)f_{Y}\left(z/x\right)$

Thanks

Comment: $f_Y(y)$ is not a probability but a density, so the [change of variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function) from $y$ to $\frac zx$ introduces an extra term, in this case $\frac{1}{|x|}$

Comment: @Henry Thanks. Conceptually, though, pdfs are proportionate to probability, so is there a  reason why the extra term isn't a constant?

Comment: Not quite: the integrals of densities are probabilities, so when you stretch or squeeze what you are integrating over through a change of variable, then you need do the opposite to the density to keep the integral the same; if your change of variable is a non-linear function then the amount you do this by will need to vary